# Process the result of an executeSql statement using Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, mustache

This is a simplified scenario:

```
var dbo = openDatabase('xxx','1.0','xxx', 1048576);
myPromise = new $.Deferred();
dbo.transaction(function(myTrans) {
    myTrans.executeSql(
        'SELECT * FROM myTable',
        [], 
        function(tx, result) {
            myPromise.resolve(result);
        }
    );
});
myPromise.done(function(result) {
    var X = $('#result-template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(X);
    template(result.rows);
});
```

I think everything is working up to the 2nd to the last line - the template(result.rows) line.

Edit: Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PhillipSenn/GUGjS/) with everything from dropping the table, creating it, populating it, selecting from it and (trying to) display the result.

Comment: Here is my http://jsfiddle.net/PhillipSenn/GUGjS/ where I'm trying to get A,B,C to show up in an unordered list.

Comment: OK, I found it.  It's because I'm not taking the result of the template function call and inserting it into the DOM.

Comment: But I think I also have to loop through result.rows.item() and build an array.  Not sure about that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line should be something like:

```
$('ul').append(template(data));
```

VOTE FOR PEDRO!